# Filter a JSON response using the pm.visualizer function

Tags: postman

I am trying out to filter a JSON response using pm.visualizer function in Postman.
This is an example of a JSON response:

```
{
"kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
"name": "vs_myOwnVS",
"partition": "TMS",
"fullPath": "/TMS/vs_myOwn_web_http_pre",
"generation": 62884
}
```

I just need to visualize name and partition key

And this is the template I´m trying:

```
let template = `
<div>
    {{#each response}}
    <h3>name:{{name}}</h3><br>
    <h3>partition:{{partition}}</h3>
    {{/each}}
</div>
`;
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
response: JSON.parse(responseBody)
});
```

I know my needs are really simple, but I'm blocked. The code doesn't have errors, but I don´t visualize any data.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't believe you would need those `{{each}}` blocks as it's not an array, judging by your response data. You could just have `{{response.name}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example response code snippet, you should just be able to do something like this in the `Tests` tab:

```js
let template = `
<div>
    <h3>name:{{name}}</h3><br>
    <h3>partition:{{partition}}</h3>
</div>
`;
pm.visualizer.set(template, pm.response.json());
```

Comment: Thanks to Danny Dainton, now I understand how it works